# reactjs - changing state doesn't re-render component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a map function to create a game board from an array of objects and calling setState on click to make the game happen. I can successfuly update the state but the view won't update until I perform a different action. I'm guessing the problem is in how the map function passes props to the child element (Cell), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
var board = [];
var width = 50;
var height = 30;
var size = width * height;


for (var i=1; i<=size; i++) {
    board[i] = {id: i, status: 'dead'};
}

var Cell = React.createClass({
  turn: function() {
    this.props.turn(this.props.id);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div id={this.props.id} className={this.props.status} onClick={this.turn}></div>
  }
});

var GameBoard = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() {    
    return {
      board: board
    };
  },

  handleClick: function(id) {
    var newBoard = this.state.board;
    newBoard[id] = {id: id, status: 'alive'};
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
  },

  move: function() {
    var board = this.state.board;
    var newBoard = board;
    for (var j=1;j<=board.length;j++) {
      if (board[j].status == 'alive') {
        newBoard[j-1] = {id: j-1, status: 'alive'};
        newBoard[j] = {id: j, status: 'dead'};
      }
    }
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
  },

  render: function() {
    var squares = this.state.board.map(function(item){
      return <Cell id={item.id} status={item.status} turn={this.handleClick}/>
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Game of Life</h1>
        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.move}>Run</button>
        <div className='boardContainer'>{squares}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<GameBoard/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

http://codepen.io/Theeeus/pen/YpQzPO?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in your `move` function is off-by-one, so it throws an error before reaching the line with `setState`. The first two lines of the method simply assign a reference to `this.state.board` in the variable `newBoard`. Therefore, you're "updating" your state, but not correctly with `setState`. That's why the board updates on your next click, which calls `setState` in `handleClick`.

1) You should modify a deep copy of the state instead of the state itself

2) Fix the off-by-one-error in the for loop

```
var board = this.state.board;
var newBoard = board; // Note, this is a reference to this.state.board. That's bad!
for (var j=1; j<=board.length - 1; j++) { // note, -1
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! Changing the loop already fixed the error but I had no idea that assigning the state to a variable would still affect the state. I'm gonna modify that part to avoid problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
 if(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
```

,instead of

```
if(var i = 1;i<=arr.length;i++){}
```

In your question,when your j in your move function equals to board.length, it will make an error.
Change your two if cycle in your code .
I hope that I can help.

```js
  var board = [];
var width = 2;
var height = 3;
var size = width * height;


for (var i=0; i < size; i++) {
    board[i] = {id: i, status: 'dead'};
}

var Cell = React.createClass({
  turn: function() {
    this.props.turn(this.props.id);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div id={this.props.id}   className={this.props.status} onClick={this.turn}></div>
  }
});
var GameBoard = React.createClass({  
  getInitialState: function() {    
    return {
      board: board
    };
  },

  handleClick: function(id) {
    var newBoard = this.state.board;
    newBoard[id] = {id: id, status: 'alive'};
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
  },

  move: function() {
    var board = this.state.board;
    var newBoard = board;
    for (var j=0;j < board.length;j++) {
      if (board[j].status == 'alive') {
        newBoard[j-1] = {id: j-1, status: 'alive'};
        newBoard[j] = {id: j, status: 'dead'};
      }
    }
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
  },

  render: function() {
    var squares = this.state.board.map(function(item){
      return <Cell key = {item.id} fuck={item.id} id={item.id} status={item.status} turn={this.handleClick}/>
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Game of Life</h1>
        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.move}>Run</button>
        <div className='boardContainer'>{squares}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<GameBoard/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
 .dead{

width:10px;height:10px;border:1px solid red;margin:3px;

      }
      .alive{
        border:1px solid green;margin:3px;width:10px;height:10px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating `this.state`. The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) specify that this is a no-no. Inside the `GameBoard` component, I'd rewrite your `handleClick()` and `move()` functions to look more like this:

```
handleClick: function(id) {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    board: [
      ...this.state.board.slice(0, id),
      {
        id,
        status: 'alive'
      },
      ...this.state.board.slice(id + 1)
    ]
  });
},

move: function() {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    board: this.state.board.map((place, id, board) => {
      const nextPlace = board[id + 1];
      if (nextPlace.status === 'alive') {
        return {
          ...place,
          status: 'alive'
        };
      } else if (place.status === 'alive') {
        return {
          ...place,
          status: 'dead'
        };
      }
      return place;
    })
  });
},
```

Note: these functions use some new Javascript features like the spread operator (`...place`) and arrow functions. It's possible that these features might result in syntax errors when you try to run this code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the spread operator but I will read through the documentation and give it a try.  thanks!